# Problems with setting up "Tax Info" in iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to set up `"Tax Info"` section in my `iTunes Connect` account.
Only few fields are available to edit. It's fields with numbers 3, 5 and field `"Title"`.

So there is nowhere to go wrong, but I'm definitely doing something wrong, because again and again I get a very same message `"Please make sure to fill out all the required fields correctly"`.

I guess, that the problem is in `"Title"` field, but I don't understand, what am I doing wrong. Or may be problem is in `"Name of Person Making this Declaration"` field. I don't know which name should be there, my, or bank account holder?

Can anybody explain me, where is my mistake, because there is no any useful information in the web.

I think, that also I should say, that I'm not US resident, so my answers on first twi questions is "No".

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Just experienced the same issue... Let me know if you find how to solve it.

Comment: Did you already set up a bank account? Your title is supposed to be Mr. or Mrs., not Developer :D And no, the name does not need to be the bank account holder's.

Comment: @LinusG. Yes, I did, but it's not updated yet. Message is "Banking update in progress, your changes should be reflected within 24 hours."

Comment: @LinusG. Sure! I'm waiting for my bank data will be updated. If you was right, I'll accept the answer immediately :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question and should be directed to Apple support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like in my case it was a bug on the Apple side, because today, when I tried to set up tax info again, it suddenly was accepted.

Also as Thomas Watson wrote, [here on the Apple site](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6986047?start=30&tstart=0), is a discussion, where people from all over the world complain about the very same problem, so everything indicates that this is a bug in Apple site system.

And also, that's what is written on iTunesConnect help: "*If your bank account information is in process for more than 24 hours, it generally indicates missing tax information.*"

So Linus G. was wrong, when he said "*Make sure the bank account is valid and accepted before proceeding to tax info.*" You **must** to set up your tax info, because you bank account **could not be accepted** without it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup a bank account before creating the tax info.
Make sure the bank account is valid and accepted before proceeding to tax info.

Your title is supposed to be Mr. or Mrs., not Developer :D  - 
And no, the name does not need to be the bank account holder's.

Comment: I think the title is meant for when you work at an organization or similar - not for when you are just submitting apps as a private person ;)

Comment: Probably, but he put *Individual*, so he should either put some position or what I suggested, I guess ;)

Comment: I have bank info set up but am getting the same error. The title is "job title" (it tells you that if you leave it blank). However it doesn't make any difference whether I put CEO, Mr or whatever. I think it must be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open issue on the Apple Support Communities website which is only a few days old. So it seems to be a bug in their systems:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6986047